# Can we start allowing questions about some of the famous third party extensions?

Tags: discussion

There are lots of Good free third party extensions available, whose questions, discussion may be useful for many of the Magento users.

Can we start allowing questions about some of the specific Third Party extensions like Magmi or Fishpig Wordpress integration etc.

This will save lots of time of other developers searching web for the solutions.

We can together create a list of extension whose discussion shall be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem with **free** extensions.

Comment: Thats great!!  so can we list out the extensions where we can allow discussions... You as a moderator could please post a question to list the free extensions based on overall feedback?

Comment: Any free extensions are ok. Or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: Yes that was my question... but still community members close the question saying it as a third party extension even though they are free.. I would suggest you should post a guideline on meta informing regarding it.

Comment: Well, I did posted this couple of times already but as you see not much of an effect.

Comment: What do you suggest in this case then?

Comment: Can the "asking" FAQ be updated to be more clear?  I became aware of this issue when asking about M2E--a free, yet very large extension.  Posting relevant code isn't necessarily possible, and the question of whether code can be reproduced without licensing issues (even for free-as-in-beer extensions) can be questionable.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic